# git svn imported repository using svn branches

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I've cloned a replicated svn repository (svnsync to local file system). All the branches etc. are now available in git.
Now i would like to start working on svn branches

```
git checkout remotes/B_XYZ
```

and doing some commits via git. 
Now i want to change to a different SVN branch via

```
git checkout remotes/B_ABC
```

and doing some changes as well.

And now the final question is: Is it possible to commit the changes i made on the branches (in git) to the original Subversion repository back on the appropriate branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experiments i figured out how to do the commit to the new repository which is not the replicated one.

```
git svn dcommit --commit-url URL/branches/BRANCHNAME
```

With the command above i can commit the changes i made in git into the new svn repository.

Answer (score 2):

Is `git svn dcommit` not working for you?

Comment: But as far as i understand the doc the git svn dcommit will commit to the location where i cloned from which is a local repository which i synced. But i would like to dcommit the changes to a different repository (e.g. http://svn.exz.de/)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that part at first. You could probably manually add some remotes, but to me it would be easier to set up a new `git svn` integration (one that actually talks to the true `svn` repo, not a copy) in a separate repository and then [`git cherry-pick`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) the changes over into it.

Comment: I used a replicated SVN repository, cause the original is currently down. That's the reason to use the replicated SVN repos instead of the original.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your SVN repository and use it instead of git-svn. It will create a pure Git repository (not git-svn repository!) for you such that any push to it will result into SVN commit and vice-versa (triggered by hooks). Any new branch push will create a branch in SVN, any tag push will create a tag.

The only restriction is that you should have an access to your SVN repostiory, but is seem it's exactly your case.

To do that run

```
$ subgit install path/to/svn/repostiory
```

The linked Git repository will be in path/to/svn/repostiory/.git.